# Is biodegradable cat litter safe to use in rat litter box?

Tags: safety, rat, cat-litter

I currently use bathing sand in my rats' litter box but I'd like to change it to something I can just flush down the toilet (it would be much more convenient). I tried using tissues but they just take them out of the box to play with. So I thought about that biodegradable soya based or corn based cat litter but I don't know if it is OK to use for rats (and I couldn't find any information on it).

Comment: is this litter intentionally for flushing down the toilette? Because "biodegradable" in my understabding says only, that it will rott and not, that it will pass the water-cleaning-processes for used water to get clean water out of it. Maybe a region tag would help, because how used water is processed could be very different.

Comment: In general you should never flush any cat litter down the toilet, biodegradable or not. That stuff clogs up the sewer and causes lots of trouble in sewer treatment plants.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://shop-cdn-m.mediazs.com/bilder/cats/best/universal/9/800/73112_pla_cats_best_universal_20l_9.jpg)? (Cat's Best Universal, not affiliated)

Comment: Anything that doesn't leave a lot of dust is a good choice. Sometimes you can buy paper scraps looking like a shredded paper, they don't take it out so eagerly like the tissues :)